# Confusing pop-up when submitting comments too quickly

Tags: feature-request, support, status-bydesign, comments

When you submit comments too fast, a pop-up shows up saying:

> Only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds; timer reset.

That confuses me. Does the `timer reset` part mean that everytime I click submit before the time's up, the 15 seconds timer gets reset, i.e., I have to wait 15 seconds after that?

- If it does, why? It's an unwanted "feature".
- If it doesn't mean that, can the wording be made a bit clearer? Maybe by omitting the "timer rest" part.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `Does the timer reset part mean that everytime I click submit before the time's up, the 15 seconds timer gets reset, i.e., I have to wait 15 seconds after that?` Yes.

Comment: Yep, so rage-clicking on the button until it accepts your comment will not work. Patience young grashopper. :)

Comment: **Moe**: Oh, boy!  The deep fryer's here.  Heh heh, I got it used from the navy.  You can flash-fry a buffalo in forty seconds.
 **Homer**: Forty seconds?  But I want it now!  ([youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9EBhaULToU))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the timer reset part mean that everytime I click submit before the time's up, the 15 seconds timer gets reset, i.e., I have to wait 15 seconds after that?

Yes, the timer is indeed reset every time you click submit. This is probably to prevent rage-clicking on the button until it accepts your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you click on the "Add Comment" button, and 15 seconds are not passed since the last time you clicked on that button, the time counter is reset, and you will need to wait 15 seconds more. That is the wanted behavior.

*Time reset* is necessary, as (differently) I would take that, when I click on "Add Comment" after 9 seconds, I still have  6 seconds to wait. I cannot find a better phrase to use; *time reset* is pretty clear to me, and I prefer it to *time has been reset*.

Comment: Oh, I see you've answered.